# Cannot read property pushState of undefined + strange url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement routing in my react application  but I have two problems:

0] the link has an ending string that I do not want:

```
http://localhost:3333/#/clients?_k=ssyjyn
```

every time I refresh the page all the char after '?_' change.

1] When I click on a link I always get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushState' of undefined
```

Examples in the react-router repository work for me but when I copy the exact same code in my application they stop working even though I get no error at all: simply if I click on a link, nothing happens.

Code is very simple:

```
  1 import React from 'react';
  2 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 import {Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router';
  4
  5 import HeaderMenu from './Header_menu';
  6
  7 import App from './App';
  8 import Appointments from './App';
  9 import Clients from './App';
 10
 11 ReactDOM.render(
 12             <div>
 13                 <HeaderMenu />
 14                 <Router>
 15                     <Route path="/" component={App}>
 16                         <Route path="appointments" component={Appointments} />
 17                         <Route path="clients" component={Clients} />
 18                     </Route>
 19                 </Router>
 20             </div>,
 21         document.getElementById('app'))
```

Header_menu:

```
  1 import React from 'react';
  2 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 import {Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router';
  4
  5 class HeaderMenu extends React.Component{
  6     render(){
  7         return(
  8             <div className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
  9                 <div className="container">
 10                     <div className="navbar-header">
 11                         <a className="navbar-toggle">·
 12                             <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 13                             <span className="icon-bar"></span>
 14                             <span className="icon-bar"></span>
 15                             <span className="icon-bar"></span>
 16                         </a>
 17                         <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
 18                     </div>
 19                     <div id="slidemenu">
 20                         <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
 21                             <li className="active"><a href="#">Appointments</a></li>
 22                             <li><Link to="/clients">Clients</Link></li>
 23                             <li><Link to="/appointments">Appointments</Link></li>
 24                         </ul>
 25                     </div>
 26                 </div>
 27             </div>
 28         );
 29     }
 30 }
 31
 32 export default HeaderMenu;
```

App/Clients/Appointments are all something like:

```
 20 const Clients = React.createClass({
 21     render(){
 22         return(
 23             <div>Clients</div>
 24         );
 25     }
 26 });
```

What problem could it be?

EDIT: added the app.js file code

```
  1 import React from 'react';
  2 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3
  4 import HeaderMenu from './Header_menu';
  5
  6 class App extends React.Component{
  7     render(){
  8         return(
  9             <div>
 10                 <HeaderMenu />
 11                 <div className='container' id='page-content'>
 12                    {this.props.children}
 13                 </div>
 14             </div>
 15         );
 16     }
 17 }
 18
 19 class Appointments extends React.Component{
 20     render(){
 21         return(
 22             <div className='col-xs-12'>
 23             appointemtns
 24             </div>
 25         );
 26     }
 27 }
 28
 29 class Clients extends React.Component{
 30     render(){
 31         return(
 32             <div>Clients</div>
 33         );
 34     }
 35 }
 36
 37 export default App
```

Comment: For the query string at the end of the URL, see [this documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your HeaderMenu inside your App component. The Router needs to be the outer most component for the history to be seen.

***UPDATE***

You probably need to add an index route to app to display or redirect to the appointment component/url. If you can paste the App code we can help verify/clarify.

***UPDATE***

If you are trying to do what I think you are... add `<IndexRoute component={Appointments}/>` under your App route.

Comment: Thank you, you are right! Now the problem is that even with {this.props.children}  on the App component the link does not display anything, just changes the url..!

Comment: Added the app js file in the first post!

Comment: What url are you going to

Comment: Line 22 and 23 of the menu: Link to='/clients' and 'appointments'. Both aren't displayed!